# Composite Attribute for Validation and UiHint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a property that represents a 'payable amount' on a number of different classes. They do not share a common base class or interface.

This property has the following rules:

- Must be greater than 0
- Must be a numeric value with no more than 2 decimal places
- Must not exceed a max length (defaults to 13)
- Use a UI Hint for "Amount"
- Add model metadata for Max Length

This property will appear a lot across a number of different systems that I am responsible for, so I'd like to have a single attribute of "PayableAmountAttribute" that will encapsulate all of this functionality. I know that I can do a composite *validation* attribute (along with metadata, by implementing `IMetadataAware`), but I'm stumped as to how to include the UI Hint as part of this attribute.

Is there a way I can combine my validation attributes and a UIHint attribute into a single attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am implementing `IMetadataAware`, I gain access to an instance of `ModelMetadata`, which allows me to set the `TemplateHint` property:

```
public class PayableAmountAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IMetadataAware
{       
    public override bool IsValid(object Value)
    {
        // Implementation of looping through validation attributes
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata Metadata)
    {
        Metadata.TemplateHint = "Amount";
        Metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("Amount.MaxLength", 10);
    }
}
```